# View report.html after DPC++ compilation for FPGA on DevCloud connected with Jupyter

Tags: linux, intel-fpga, intel-oneapi, dpc++

I already got report.html (optimization report), but don't known how to view it.

I tried complete command "firefox repotr.html" and expecting open it by web browser Firefox, but got:
`Command 'firefox' not found, but can be installed with: apt install firefox Please ask your administrator.`

Further I attempt to install it by command "apt install firefox", but of course I have "Permission denied":
`E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied) E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?`

Comment: What browsers *are* installed on your computer? Do you have permissions to actually use `sudo` on it, or is your computer managed by your sysadmin?

Comment: I use Intel DevCloud connected with Jupyter. All hardware are placed in cloud and does not belong to me. I probably don't have admin rights according to the outputs. I don't know which browsers are installed on cloud-machine.

Comment: You may wish to consider downloading the file and viewing it locally if permitted. After all, it is an HTML file. Otherwise, you may want to see if devcloud has specific documentation, given that they control the setup. Other users may know of it, but I unfortunately don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've raised a [thread](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-DevCloud/View-report-html-after-DPC-compilation-for-FPGA-on-DevCloud/m-p/1472409#M7854) in Intel Communities.

Currently, The only suggested way is to download the report onto your local machine and view it, as Intel DevCloud is a shared environment which comes with pre-installed validated Intel oneAPI software and complimentary packages. User's don't have admin privileges to install other packages.